# Node.js module for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, node.js

There are several MongoDB modules available for Node.js in the following link -
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-nosql-mongo

Please, suggest me one (I'd like to know why you choose that one?).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on what level of abstraction you want from your data. If you want something similar to an ORM, then [**Mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/) is the obvious choice and is popular.

However, the [**node-mongodb-native**](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native#readme) driver gives you clean duplication of almost the entire MongoDB API and since BSON is translated to JSON and JavaScript is a flexible dynamic language, there's really no need for an ORM. The latter does have benefits such a defining a schema which helps with validation and other tasks, but it also limits your flexibility.

[**Mongoskin**](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin) is built atop node-mongodb-native but gives you the ability to have additional JavaScript method bindings and deal with connections and cursors easier. It's pretty lightweight, so you can stick with the basics or do more. **This library is my personal preference** and our team has built our own tooling and validation system around it.

Comment: I work with Chris F. The main reason in our case not to use Mongoose was testing. Mongoose objects are declare in the collection and make testing (and mocking) a bit difficult.

Comment: Congrats, You have 2013 reps now, happy new year 2013 :)

Answer (score 7):

[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) is a popular choice. But the documentation is just as bad (if not worse) than the MongoDB docs.

Comment: I do agree. Docs for Mongoose made me chose another node module for my MongoDB projects.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer [Mongolian](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian), it's the closest thing you get to the Mongo shell and it's straight forward to use.

My [fork](https://github.com/OneOfOne/node-mongolian) adds very simple collection initialization.

Comment: This is not maintained anymore. Last commit was like 4 years ago.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu do you realize this answer is from 2011?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change the fact the library is not maintained  anymore ...

Comment: Does bulk insert is possible by Mongolian ?

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose doesn't support bulk insert and it is schema-based. When you try to create different schemas for same collection, it throws exception. Consider carefully its suitability to your case before start with it.

Comment: You're right. Mongoose is more like SQL-based with its schema-based policy. IMHO this does prevent people from understanding the very schemaless principle of document-based policy.